# Button press doesn't work during parsing

Tags: objective-c, parsing

I cannot make `back` button (previous page in navigation) work during html parsing process. What I am trying to do is parsing an html and get a pdf file on `viewDidAppear`. During that time I want `back` button to be enabled because parsing can take long time. So users can decide to leave parsing process.

here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(getPDFUrl) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

-(void) getPDFUrl
{
    NSURL *programURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/somepdf/"];
    NSData *programHtmlData;
    @try
    {
        programHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:programURL];
    }
    @catch(NSException* ex)
    {}
    // 2
    TFHpple *programHTMLParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:programHtmlData];

    NSString *studiosXpathQueryString =
    @"//div[@class='ultra_wrapper']/div[@class='container columns extra_pad boxed_lay centered']/div[@id='prk_ajax_container']/div[@id='centered_block']/div[@id='main_block']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='main']/div[@class='twelve columns sidebarized']/div[@class='prk_no_composer']/p/a";
    NSArray *programNodes = [programHTMLParser searchWithXPathQuery:studiosXpathQueryString];
    NSMutableArray *activities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Tutorial *tutorial;

    if (programNodes.count > 0) {

        for (TFHppleElement *element in programNodes)
        {

            @try
            {
                tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
                tutorial.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
            }
            @catch(NSException* ex)
            {

            }
        }

        NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tutorial.url];
        webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"warning"
                                                        message:@"warning!"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your probably blocking the main thread which is what the UI needs to actually do it's thing. You need to make the parser run in the background so have a look at `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(getPDFUrl) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

will execute on main thread. **Therefore Blocking your UI**.

You should use

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getPDFUrl) withObject:nil];
```

Or you can use `NSOperationQueue` or just `NSOperation` or more simple way `NSBlockOperation`.

```
NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

   NSLog(@"dasds");

}];

[op start];
```

Comment: yes, such a mistake. thanks very much, it works now.